# IntPtr conversion to a struct monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have bindings to an objective c library:

```
[Export ("getParsedStatus::")]
[CompilerGenerated]
public virtual void GetParsedStatus (IntPtr starPrinterStatus, global::System.UInt32 level)
{
    if (IsDirectBinding) {
        Definition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_StarPrinterStatus_UInt32 (this.Handle, selGetParsedStatus_Handle, starPrinterStatus, level);
    } else {
        Definition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_StarPrinterStatus_UInt32 (this.SuperHandle, selGetParsedStatus_Handle, starPrinterStatus, level);
    }
}
```

where the original objective c library function looks like :

```
(void)getParsedStatus:(void *)starPrinterStatus :(u_int32_t)level;
```

Everything seems to be working with my C# code:

```
SMPort port = null;
Byte[] commands = null;
uint totalAmountWritten = 0;
uint commandSize=0;
StarPrinterStatus_2 stat;
IntPtr status;
private void test()
{
    try{
        stat = new StarPrinterStatus_2();

        port = new SMPort(new NSString("BT:PRNT Star"), new NSString("mini"), 10000);

        status = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(stat));

        port.GetParsedStatus( status ,(uint) 2);
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(status, stat);
        port.BeginCheckedBlock(status, (uint) 2);

        commands = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x40, 0x1b, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x1b, 0x45, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x7b, 0x00, 0x1d, 0x42, 0x00, 0x1d, 0x21, 0x31,0x1d, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x61, 0x31, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA };

        IntPtr ptr2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(commands.Length*4);

        int i = 0;
        foreach(byte b in commands)
        {
            Marshal.WriteByte(ptr2,i*4, b);
        }

        totalAmountWritten = 0;
        commandSize = (uint)commands.Length;

        //while (totalAmountWritten < commandSize)
        //foreach(byte b in commands)
        //{
            uint remaining = commandSize - totalAmountWritten;
            uint amountWritten = port.WritePort(ptr2, totalAmountWritten, remaining);
            totalAmountWritten += amountWritten;
        //}

        port.EndCheckedBlock(status, (uint) 2);

        //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(status);
    //  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr2);
        Port.ReleasePort(port);

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show (ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

However, when I call lets say `port.GetParsedStatus( status ,(uint) 2);` how do I convert status into a struct...I have tried marshaling but that produces an error. Everything else seems to be working right - as in I am able to get the printer to a little bit of printing even though they are random characters I assume that the my program is actually communicating with the printer - which means that the bindings and library are all working well...its just a matter of getting the IntPtr to a struct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to declare the binding as a pointer to the struct:

```
 public void GetParsedStatus (ref StarPrinterStatus_2 starPrinterStatus, uint level);
```

and then just use it like this:

```
 port.GetParsedStatus (ref stat, (uint) 2);
```